# OpenGL: how to pass vertex pos from Geometry shader to fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, geometry-shader

I am currently learning shaders in OpenGL and finished writing my "drawText" geometry shader, so I can draw dynamic text ( content change every frame ), without recreating VBO every frame.

It's working nicely but it's limited to 28 chars, because of the GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS limitations that is equal 1024.

ATM I have 6 components per vertex emitted vec4 pos and vec2 texCoord.
Which give me 1024/6 = 170 vertices to use for my triangle strip.

I need 6 vertices per char ( instead first and last char ) to display a quad per char and 2 vertices to move to next char with degenerated triangle.
That gives me 170/6 = 28 chars.

So when I have a long text, I split it into text of 28 chars.

So now I try to optimize that and get my geometry shader to draw more than 28 chars.
So because I am in 2D, I was trying to find a way to store the texCoord in the pos.zw for the fragment shader. and remove the out vec2 texCoord in my geometry shader. Which will make me emit only 4 components per vertex, which would bring me to 42 chars.

But reading the fragment shader doc and fragment systems input I don't see who to do this.
So, is there a way to achieve that?

My code for reference

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;

uniform vec2    textPosition;
void main()
{
    gl_Position     = vec4(aPos ,0, 1) + vec4(textPosition, 0, 0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

out     vec4        fragColor;
in      vec2        texCoord;

uniform vec4        textColor;
uniform sampler2D   outTexture;

void main()
{
    fragColor = texture(outTexture, texCoord) * textColor;
}
```

Geometry Shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 170) out; 
// max components and vertices are 1024
// vec4 pos and vec2 text coord per vertex, that 6 components per vertex, 1024 / 6 = 170

out     vec2    texCoord;

uniform float   screenRatio         = 1;
uniform float   fontRatio           = 1;
uniform float   fontInterval        = 0;        // distance between letters
uniform float   fontSize            = 0.025f;   // default value, screen coord range is -1f , 1f  
uniform int     textString[8];                  // limited to 28 chars . 170 vertices / 6 = 28, 28 / 4 = 7 ints.

void main() 
{    
    vec4 position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;

    float fsx   = fontSize * fontRatio * screenRatio;
    float fsy   = fontSize;
    float tsy    = 1.0f / 16.0f;                // fixed in a 16x16 chars bitmap
    float tsx    = tsy;
    float tw     = tsx * fontRatio;
    float to     = ( tsx - tw ) * 0.5f;

    vec4  ptl = position + vec4(0,0,0,0);     // top left
    vec4  ptr = position + vec4(fsx,0,0,0);   // top right
    vec4  pbl = position + vec4(0,fsy,0,0);   // bottom left
    vec4  pbr = position + vec4(fsx,fsy,0,0); // bottom right
    vec2  tt;                                 // tex coord top
    vec2  tb;                                 // tex coord bottom

    fsx += fontInterval;

    int i  = 0;                               // index in int array
    int si = 0;                               // sub index in int
    int ti = textString[0];
    int ch = 0;

    do
    {
        // unpack a char, 4 chars per int
        ch  = (ti >> si) & (0xFF);

        // string ends with \0 or end of array
        if ( ch == 0 || i >= 8)
            break;

        // compute row and col of char in bitmaps 16x16 chars
        int   r   = ch >> 4;
        int   c   = ch - ( r << 4 );

        // compute tex coord from row and column
        tb = vec2(c * tsx + to, 1.0f - r     * tsy);
        tt = vec2(tb.x        , tb.y - tsy);

        texCoord    = tt;
        gl_Position = ptl;
        EmitVertex();   
        EmitVertex();   
        texCoord    = tb;
        gl_Position = pbl;
        EmitVertex();

        tt.x += tw;
        tb.x += tw;

        texCoord    = tt;
        gl_Position = ptr;
        EmitVertex();   

        texCoord    = tb;
        gl_Position = pbr;
        EmitVertex();
        EmitVertex();

        // advance of 1 char
        ptl.x += fsx;
        ptr.x += fsx;
        pbl.x += fsx;
        pbr.x += fsx;

        si += 8;
        if ( si >= 32 )
        {
            si = 0;
            ++i;
            ti = textString[i];
        }
    }
    while ( true );

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Comment: "*so I can draw dynamic text ( content change every frame ), without recreating VBO every frame.*" You really shouldn't bother. Even if you're drawing entire pages of text all on top of each other, it won't hurt your performance if you use [reasonable streaming techniques](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).

Comment: "*I need 6 vertices per char ( instead first and last char ) to display a quad per char*" No, you only need 4 vertices to output a quad.

Comment: if you use triangle strip and you don't want 2 consecutive quad to touch, you need 6 vertices.

Well, I do care because I want to learn openGL ,  I already know how to draw text using other methods , and already implemented

Comment: "*if you use triangle strip and you don't want 2 consecutive quad to touch, you need 6 vertices.*" That's what `EndPrimitive()` is for. You use 4 vertices per-quad, and then you end the primitive.

Comment: I am doing 1 triangle strip per text not per char, read the code.

Comment: "*I am doing 1 triangle strip per text not per char, read the code.*" I read your code. I'm saying that this is the *wrong way* to do it. Now, do you want to output more characters, or are you invested in doing things the wrong way?

Comment: "*Well, I do care because I want to learn openGL*" Why would you want to learn a *less efficient* way of doing things? Your rendering system requires making multiple uniform state changes just to render sequences of text. Uniform state changes aren't free. An efficient renderer would make a single draw call for all of the characters.

Comment: My question is not about is is the right way or not to draw text using geometry shader instead of a VBO, I already have this done. My question is about learning more about geometry shader. If you don't want to answer the question don't.
If I want to ask what is the most efficient way to draw dynamic text in openGL I know how to use google. Thanks.

Comment: "*My question is about learning more about geometry shader.*" There are plenty of ways to use a GS that *aren't* less efficient ways of accomplishing a task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of a vertex to be sent to the rasterizer, as defined through `gl_Position`, contains 4 components. Always. And the meaning of those components is defined by the rasterizer and the OpenGL rendering system.

You cannot bypass or otherwise get around it. The output position has 4 components, and you cannot hide texture coordinates or other arbitrary data within them.

If you need to output more stuff from the GS, then you need to more efficiently use your GS's vertex output. As it currently stands, you output degenerate strips between each quad. This means that for every 6 vertices, only 4 of them are meaningful. You're using degenerate strips to split quads.

Instead of doing that, you should use `EndPrimitive` to split your quads. That will remove 1/3rd of all of your vertex output, giving you more components to put to actual good use.

Comment: okay, so that's an interesting thing I didn't know and was not explained in the tutorial I read, I can actually call EndPrimitive() several  times in the same geometry shader?
I am going to try that , it will save me 2 vertices.Thanks.